# Why mobx inject needs to use react's context?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

What are the potential issues to implement a `@inject` decorator which does not depend to `mobx-react`'s `Provider` component (which stores its properties in react's context)?

The usage of the `inject` would be something like this:

```
// MyComponent.js

import { authManager } from './services';

const MyComponent = ({ authManager }) => ...;

export default inject({ authManager })(MyComponent);
```

It just merges its parameter with component props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a function as the first argument into the inject function.
https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#customizing-inject

```
import { authManager } from './services';
inject(_stores => ({ authManager }))(YouComponent);
```

It will not depend on the context, it will just map the returned object to your props.

*I didn't tested it*